# Failed to authenticate password. Error using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i am trying to send mail using codeigniter "email" library it is giving an authentication error. I have already modified the "auth_username" and "auth_password" in "sendmail.ini" file. 
I can't get any way from where I should start to solve the problem. Any help please....

[image: Error image]

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        // 'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
        // 'mailpath' => "/usr/bin/sendmail",
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => $sender,
        'smtp_pass' => $senderPass,
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($sender);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($body);
    if(!$this->email->send())
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Comment: try smtp => smtp.gmail.com

Comment: you said to use 'protocol'=>'smtp.gmail.com' instead of 'protocol'=>'smtp' ? @MuhammadUsman

Comment: Please paste your code instead of an image.

Comment: Edited. check it now please @MuhammadUsman

Comment: try this 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',

Comment: no change. same error @MuhammadUsman